# syntax error running Tensorflow on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have installed Tensorflow on Ubuntu. Wen want to test Tensorflow I get this syntax  error:

```
VirtualBox:~$ # Python
VirtualBox:~$ import tensorflow as tf
VirtualBox:~$ hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

I use ubuntu on virtual machine.how could I fix this error?
I wanted to follow this video  to install Ubuntu on Windows:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLX2pLg1rWw

Comment: Why are you running the python statements in shell? Aren't you supposed to do it in a Python interpreter interface like ipython?

Comment: I am new to Linux. I just wanted to follow this video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YLX2pLg1rWw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't start python and bash doesn't understand your import statement. Type python hit enter (not Python). Then there should be a prompt like >>> .
Now run the statements import and so on.